# Escaping a complicated string

Tags: c#, string, escaping, character

Basicly, I wan't to know how I would go about escaping this:

```
"\"
```

By the above, I mean all of the three characters.
This is what I've got so far, but which doesn't compile.

```
t = FindAndReplace("\"SLASH\"", "@\\"\"\\");
```

So in other words. I have the text **"SLASH"** which should be replaced by **"\"** through this.

Comment: uhm, if i got it right you are asking for this: t = yourString.Replace("\"SLASH\"",  @"""\""");

Comment: You can encode any string by doing a find/replace of `"` with `""`, then putting that in a verbatim string: `@""`. E.g. this would be `@"""\"""`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the first quote as `\"`, then escape the slash as `\\`, then the final quote again with `\"`. The whole thing is then wrapped in quotes, like this:

```
t = FindAndReplace("\"SLASH\"", "\"\\\"");
```

The `@` notation is useful when your string contains many backslash tokens and you don't want to have to escape them all, for example in path names:

```
string x = "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft\\Some Folder\\";
```

Is functionally equivalent to:

```
string x = @"C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Some Folder\";
```

Using `@` notation permits quotes to be encoded by writing them twice, so the potentially more readable answer to the original question is:

```
t = FindAndReplace("\"SLASH\"", @"""\""");
```

Comment: Alternatively `t = FindAndReplace(@"""SLASH""", @"""\""");`, which might be easier to read.

Comment: Awesome ;) I appreciate all the comments and answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your second tring is actually being seen as

```
"@\"\"\"
```

Which is two strings with an "\" in the middle. For your very first question, the answer is:

```
"\"\\\""
```

If this isn't what you mean in your code, then please clarify your question.